# Нет звука в Ubuntu после установки системы

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Установил недавно 2 системой последнюю версию Ubuntu, система работает, но никак не могу наладить звук. Как установил звук не появлялся вообще. Что делать, куда копать? Пробовал в терминале играться ползунками, не помогло.
[image: Фото из терминала]
[image: Фото из настроек]

Comment: очень мало информации. Начните с этого https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-nosound.html.en. А в сам вопрос добавьте версию вашей системы и конфигурацию железа. На данный момент вопрос офтоп, поскольку невозможно дать объективный ответ, а только догадки и предположения

Comment: Покажите скриншот терминала. Звук в ALSA выключен by default.

Comment: устройство вывода попробуй поменять.

Comment: Устройства вывода пробовал менять. Может стоит установить по старее версию Ubuntu?